# Quantifying Over Datatypes

Tags: z3

In playing around with Z3Py, I've defined an integer list as follows:

```
List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('cons', ('head', IntSort()), ('tail', List))
List.declare('nil')
List = List.create()
```

Now, I'm after defining some simple functions over that list such as the following:

```
len = Function('len', List, IntSort())

def len_defn():
  ls = List('ls')
  return And([
    len(List.nil) == 0,
    ForAll(ls, Implies(List.is_cons(ls), len(ls) == 1+len(List.tail(ls))))
  ])
```

Unfortunately, this ultimately fails since `ls = List('ls')` throws the error:

```
AttributeError: DatatypeSortRef instance has no __call__ method
```

Attempts at using `ls = Var(0, List)` throw:

```
AttributeError: DatatypeRef instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Does anyone have any ideas how one should generally handle quantification over datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a constant of sort `List`, we should use the procedure `Const`.

```
ls = Const('ls', List)
```

In Z3Py, the procedures `ForAll` and `Exists` are based on the C APIs that take Z3 constants as arguments. Most users find these C APIs easier to use than the ones based on de Bruijn indices.

Another issue, we should not redefine `len`. `len` is a Python builtin function. 
To avoid problems in your program, we should use

```
Len = Function('len', List, IntSort())
```

Here is the rewritten example ([also available online here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/5RPs))

```
List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('cons', ('head', IntSort()), ('tail', List))
List.declare('nil')
List = List.create()
Len = Function('len', List, IntSort())

def len_defn():
  ls = Const('ls', List)
  return And([
    Len(List.nil) == 0,
    ForAll(ls, Implies(List.is_cons(ls), Len(ls) == 1+Len(List.tail(ls))))
  ])

print len_defn()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re-reading the Z3Py tutorial (specifically the Functions section), I can see where I've gone wrong. The section talks about modelling variables as uninterpreted constants, and then uses syntax such as `x = Int('x')` to define a variable. I guess that the underlying apply method wraps up a call to `Const('x', IntSort())` here? Thanks for the reminder regarding looking at the underlying C functions for additional information.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. `Int('x')` is just syntax sugar for `Const('x', IntSort())`.